# Objective-C retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers throws "unrecognized selector sent to instance" error

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

due to some method depreciated in IOS7, i'm trying to reform a previous written  section of code:

```
CFUUIDRef peripheralUUID = CFUUIDCreateFromString(NULL, (CFStringRef)deviceUUID); //deviceUUID was previously assigned with string
[_manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)peripheralUUID]];
```

The previous code works perfectly well, but as "retrievePeripherals" goes no more in IOS7, i've made the following adjustment under the same environment:

```
NSUUID *nsuuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:deviceUUID];
NSArray *uuids = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:nsuuid, nil];
NSArray *connectedPeripherals = [_manager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:uuids];
```

Then error comes with like **[CBConcreteCentralManager retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1fd2b1b0**

The memory address was pointing towards **_manager**,

NSUUID stored was like <__NSConcreteUUID 0x210dd370> 1FDAA349-BB09-DA19-FD9E-39077890F003

and i'm sure the array **uuids** was loaded with object.

I'm not sure which parts messed up, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you linked your application with iOS7 libraries? Such error may be raised because you still use the iOS6 libraries that do not contain the method in question.

Comment: @allprog Thanks for the comment, i double checked with CoreBluetooth Framework and the CBCentralManager.h i linked to, its under version IOS7 and it did contain retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers such method, but such error still exists.  Won't XCODE popup error during compile if you're using an non-existing method?

Comment: I think something is messed up in your project's configuration but I can't tell exactly what. Can you do an experiment: right after you initialize the CBCentralManager, list all the methods it implements with the class_copyMethodList method. Like so: http://pagesofinterest.net/blog/2012/01/listing-methods-at-runtime-in-objective-c/ Check out if the retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers is included. At least you'll see what methods exist on the object.

Comment: @allprog Thanks for the suggest, the scan result shows method retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers not exist. Since my project deployment target was IOS5.0 onwards. As referring to the method in the library `- (NSArray *)retrievePeripheralsWithIdentifiers:(NSArray *)identifiers NS_AVAILABLE(NA, 7_0);` if that (NA, 7_0) means only IOS7.0 onwards, then thats the problem (i was testing it on IOS6 device)

Comment: Ok, I didn't suppose you were using an iOS6 device. :)